# Замена %20 в ссылке

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, url

Возможно ли в ссылке 
http://test/phone=%20380999123123
%20 заменить на +   и выводить все это в адресную строку?

Comment: %20 это пробел. Плюс - это %2B

Comment: Выводить в адресной строке вроде бы нельзя, потому что плюс - это специальный символ, который заменяется на пробел

Comment: Мне автоматически добавляет %20 хотя номер с +

Comment: не понимаю что вы хотите? делайте любую строку и пропихивайте ее через `urlencode()` он там сам разберется что можно а что лучше переделать.

Comment: Пробел появился потому что изначально где-то не экранировали плюс.

Answer (score 1):

Например если вы через `JavaScript` хотите это сделать, а после обратиться через такую ссылку к серверу, то для этого, как-раз и используется метод `encodeURIComponent` или `encodeURI` - которые как-раз и заменяют пробелы на `%20` - для обратного декодирования используется метод `decodeURIComponent` или `decodeURI`.

Чтобы заменить на `+` нужно воспользоваться методом `replace`.

```
var str = '%20380999123123%20';
console.log(decodeURIComponent(str).replace(/ /g,'+')); // +380999123123+
```

`decodeURIComponent` - в данном случае бесполезен, так-как, можно воспользоваться таким вариантом:

```
var str = '%20380999123123%20';
console.log(str.replace(/%20/g,'+')); // +380999123123+
```

Но вот если вдруг, будут другие закодированные символы, то как-раз `decodeURIComponent` принесет пользу.

В случае с `php`, нужно воспользоваться сначала функцией `urldecode`, а потом `urlencode`:

```
$str = '%20380999123123%20';
$str = urldecode($str);
echo urlencode($str); // +380999123123+
```

Answer (score -3):

```
  this.phone = url.searchParams.get("phone").replace(' ', '+');
```